# Understanding the proof that the image of an embedding between manifolds is a submanifold + Alternate Proof

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem on Page 17 of Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology:

Theorem: An embedding $f : X \rightarrow Y$ maps $X$ diffeomorphically onto a submanifold of $Y$.

The proof proceeds with two main steps:

1. Showing that the image of any open set in $X$ is an open set in $f(X)$ (this apparently proves that $f(X)$ is a manifold), and then
2. Checking that $f : X \rightarrow f(X)$ is a diffeomorphism.

I understand the the argument that $f$ maps open sets to open sets (which is argued by contradiction considering a sequence), but I **don't understand why this guarantees that $f(X)$ is a manifold**.

Any hints/explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the charts on $f(X)$ explicitly. Let $q\in f(X)$ and consider $p=f^{-1}(q)$. Let $(U,\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a chart on $X$ centered at $p$. It follows that $V=f(U)\subset f(X)$ is an open neighborhood of $q$, moreover, we see

$$
(V,(\varphi\circ f\vert_V^{-1}):V\to\mathbb{R}^n)
$$

defines a chart on $f(X)$ centered at $q$. Now just check the transition maps are smooth (this follows since they are smooth on $X$).

Now it is clear that $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image because 1) $f$ is bijective onto its image by assumption and 2) $f$ is a local diffeomorphism by the above.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared up my confusion perfectly